# putting <a> and <p> in one line when text is centrally align

Tags: html, css

heyy guys,
 i have this problem were i'm putting  and

in one line when text is centrally align and it keeps skipping align between each  and

this is how it looks like:

```
<div id="footercont">
                <a href="#"> A propos de So Home </a><p>I</p>
                <a href="#"> FAQ </a><p>I</p>
                <a href="#"> Contact </a><p>I</p>
                <a href="#"> Parrainage </a><p>I</p>
                <br>
                <a href="#"> Plan du site </a><p>I</p>
                <a href="#"> Conditions générales de vente </a><p>I</p>
                <a href="#"> Données personnelles </a><p>I</p>
                <a href="#"> Parrainage </a>
            </div>
```

this is how i want it to look like:
A propos de So Home  I  FAQ  I  Contact  I  Parrainage
Plan du site  I  Conditions générales de vente  I  Données personnelles

and this is the css code:

```
div#footercont{
    margin: 0;
    width: 980px;
    height: 196px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -490px;
    background: rgb(248,248,248);
    text-align: center;
}

div#footercont a{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgb(187,189,188);
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
}

div#footercont p{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgb(187,189,188);
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

would really much like to have some help on this matter, thanks!

Comment: found the answer, just had to use display:inline;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` is a block level element and hence it will take up 100% of horizontal space, so you need to make it `display: inline-block;` or `display: inline;`

But am not sure why you need `p` here, I think you want to target that text separately, so inorder to achieve that, you should consider using `span` element instead which is also an `inline` element like `a`.

Comment: thanks alot, i was using p so i can create dividers using "I" between each <a> since in my current case it looks much nicer than a border. thanks alot im still new at this.

Comment: @user3023347 So I would suggest you to study about `block` and `inline` level elements :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using css3 and want separator between each item then remove unwanted paragraph tag and try below css

```
#footercont a:after {
    content: "|";
    padding-left:8px;
}
#footercont a:last-child:after {
    content: "";
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gE7h2/)**

Comment: Actually this doesn't solve the question, it's just an alternate way to achieve what OP was trying to achieve.. so shouldn't be marked as correct anyways..

Comment: Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked.

Comment: Accepting an answer means it solves the questions doubt, obviously your solution is true, but person looking for that why `p` element renders below won't get any information from your answer, but my answer clearly explains the scenario, I can optimize great amount of CSS for him but I focused on the question rather than providing alternate solutions